# How can I open the Facebook Messenger from UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I can open Faceebok app with

```
LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:"));
```

A Facebook Messenger have link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this protocol link:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb-messenger:/"));
```

If you want to launch Messenger with specified dialog use this:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb-messenger://user-thread/{user id}"));
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you know that from? Is there any kind of documentation (maybe for all apps) I missed?

Comment: @schumi1331 FB Messenger port from iOS, so I googled iOS url) it's work)